# Maximum number of receptacles on a circuit in the UK?

Tags: electrical

I have a single plug socket in my garage but want to install more.

What would be the maximum amount of safe sockets be from that one socket?

I'm located in the UK.

Comment: You're not limited by the number of sockets, but by the number and size of the loads plugged in.

Comment: So I am basically free to install as many as I want as long as I don't plug too many things in?

Comment: I'm not familiar with UK electrical codes and standards, so the codes/laws might set a limit.  Electrically speaking, an unused receptacle has no significant current draw. So there shouldn't be a problem installing as many as you like.

Comment: If you put that as an answer I can mark it as answered. Thanks.